# Private methods within constructor (Javascript, bad idea?)

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-5

When we declare a method within the prototype object we simply have a single location in memory in which we can later invoke methods from however using the idea of *private* methods we will re-create the methods in memory every single time we create a new child.

Just for visual sake have a look at both structures below:

```
function Person(firstname, lastname){
  this.firstname = firstname,
  this.lastname = lastname
}

Person.prototype.getFullName = function() {
  return this.firstname + ' ' + this.lastname;
}

var ham = new Person('Hamoodi', 'Josef');
```

Okay so the above code creates a method and stores it within our prototype object, great stuff.

```
function Person(firstname, lastname){
  this.firstname = firstname,
  this.lastname = lastname,

    this.getFullName = function() {
      return this.firstname + ' ' + this.lastname;
    }
}
```

from what I've understood (please correct me if i'm wrong) this is how i create a *private* method, this just seems like a bad idea if we need to create many children, or am i just missing the point?

Any thoughts?

Comment: That is not a private method...

Comment: @epascarello can you please edit it? So i can see the difference

Comment: Look at revealing module pattern

Comment: @JamesThorpe, thank you for the reply, my question, may have been asked very badly, I read that we can add private methods and variables within a function constructor and that it will be private to itself, however i was simply wondering if that is such a good idea, simply because when we create many children it will allocate the methods/variables into memory again and again.

Comment: @epascarello, thanks will do!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is nothing private about the way you defined `getFullName` function. It will be available on any `Person` instance, and copied across each instance. This is why methods are put on the prototype of the Constructor so that they are shared across instances.

If you were to truly have a private function inside your constructor, it would look something like this:

```
function Person(firstname, lastname){
  // bind the function to this instance
  var getFullName = (function () {
      return this.firstname + ' ' + this.lastname;
  }).bind(this);

  this.firstname = firstname;
  this.lastname = lastname;
  // call private function and set property
  this.fullName = getFullName();
}
```

This again suffers the negative impact that each instance will create its own copy of this private method (but at least this time its scope is actually private).

Private methods usually make sense as "utility" type methods. For example, consider the following:

```
// your javascript file
(function (global) {

    // private scope
    var id = 0,
    getId = function () {
        return ++id;
    };

    function Person(firstname, lastname) {
        // call private method to get id
        this.id = getId();
        this.firstname = firstname;
        this.lastname = lastname;
    }

    // expose globally
    global.Person = Person;

}(window));
```

Now when somebody uses your API to create a new person, it uses the privately available getId function to assign a unique id to that person. Hopefully this demonstrates when you would think about using private state vs. methods publicly available on the prototype.

Comment: Nicely Done! I was typing out an example of the revelation pattern. Your's is much more elegant.

Comment: Fantastic, thanks so much for the explanation, very helpful!

Answer (score 0):

One way to get private methods in a given module, is to just define them in a scope unreachable by other API consumers.

Note that this can make unit testing a challenge, though in Node.js you can use something like [rewire](https://github.com/jhnns/rewire) to gain access to the private function.

```
function Person(firstname, lastname){
  this.firstname = firstname,
  this.lastname = lastname,

  getFullName.call( this );
}

function getFullName() {
  return this.firstname + ' ' + this.lastname;
}
```